# Running total and reading reset

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that stores hourmeter reading for our machines. The readings are stored as a running total, so every read, that occurs several times a month, is an accumulated total.

The thing is, sometimes the meter breaks, and they are replaced. In that case, the reading type changes from ACTUAL to RESET, and the reading is reset to the new value, breaking the running total.

I have a query that gets the MAX of the meter reading per month, so I can get the last reading, so I can join with another table in Tableau to make a visualization comparing maintenance costs with operating hours.

My current query is like this:

```
select assetnum,
  to_date(to_char(readingdate, 'MM/')||'01/'||to_char(readingdate, 'YYYY'), 'MM/DD/YYYY') reading_date,
  max(reading) month_reading
from meterreading
group by assetnum, to_char(readingdate, 'MM/')||'01/'||to_char(readingdate, 'YYYY')
order by to_date(to_char(readingdate, 'MM/')||'01/'||to_char(readingdate, 'YYYY'), 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

This returns a table like this:

```
Assetnum  readingdate  month_reading
8021      01/01/2016   3500
8021      02/01/2016   4200
8021      03/01/2016   5100
8021      04/01/2016   5900
8021      05/01/2016   6300
8021      06/01/2016    200      <-- meter was reset
8021      07/01/2016    350
8021      08/01/2016    403
```

So, I've envisioned two ways of fixing this:

1) I find a way to add the last reading to the current one, if the meter gets reset, or

2) Remove the accumulation, and on each reading simply get the current month reading, so it doesn't matter if it gets reset

I'm leaning more towards option 2, but I'd like to hear you opinion.

BTW, as I mentioned above, the source table have a field called readingtype, which says ACTUAL if is a regular reading, or RESET if the hourmeter was replaced.

Thanks for the help

UPDATE!!!

What I'd like to achive is this:

```
Assetnum  readingdate  month_reading
8021      01/01/2016   3500
8021      02/01/2016   4200
8021      03/01/2016   5100
8021      04/01/2016   5900
8021      05/01/2016   6300
8021      06/01/2016   6500      <-- add the current to the previous
8021      07/01/2016   6850
8021      08/01/2016   7253
```

Or this:

```
Assetnum  readingdate  month_reading
8021      01/01/2016   3500
8021      02/01/2016   700      <-- get the monthly value, not accumulated
8021      03/01/2016   900
8021      04/01/2016   800
8021      05/01/2016   400
8021      06/01/2016    200      <-- meter was reset, so no matter
8021      07/01/2016    350
8021      08/01/2016    403
```

Hope is clearer now

Comment: What are you trying to fix?  What results do you want?

Comment: Check the update. Hope is more clear now

Comment: I assume the base table will remain unchanged (you are not trying to update the "base data"), and what you are looking for is a query - or a view - that will show the "correct" totals or perhaps just monthly increments? In your base table, which rows are marked "RESET" - just the FIRST TIME (first month) there was a reset, or all the following months? Also, what happens if a meter is reset in the middle of a month - that month will show a lower total than it should and the RESET month will show more, is that OK business-wise?

Comment: Correct. I just need a query, so I can join it with another query for visualization. And the row marked RESET is just the first one of the series. The subsequent readings are marked ACTUAL, unless there is another reset later, which also happens. Maybe not in the same month, but later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the RESET readingtype value is attached only to the first full month after a reset, the second approach is easy to implement. To get the "monthly usage" you would use

```
case readingtype when 'RESET' then month_reading
                 else month_reading - lag(month_reading) 
                                      over (partition by assetnum order by readingdate)
end as monthly_usage
```

in your SELECT clause.

In any case, even without the help of `readingtype`, you can rewrite the `case` expression to test for `month_reading < lag(month_reading) over ...` (which is the marker of a RESET); do take advantage of `readingtype` if it's already there though.

ADDED:  Apparently, the very first monthly reading for each asset is not marked "RESET" (which makes it different from all the other "first" readings). This causes a problem, because for the very first reading for each asset, lag(...) is NULL (there is no previous reading) and therefore the difference is NULL as well.

This can be fixed. Instead of subtracting `lag(...) over (...)`, one needs to subtract

`nvl( lag(...) over (...), 0 )`

That is, subtract the lagging value UNLESS it is null, in which case subtract 0.

Comment: Ok, almost there. Now is missing the first reading of every asset. Is there a way I can identify the first record when a new assetnum is read?

Comment: Hehe, that is a logical flaw... the first reading should always be marked RESET, even when it's the very first reading for a new asset. This can be fixed easily, I'll add to my answer.

Comment: Ok, I made the changes, and now I believe is working as expected on the 1st row. Although, I'm getting some weird spikes in the data. I don't know what it is, really.
BTW, I stopped using readingtype, since I found some records on which the meter was reset, but readingtype was ACTUAL. So it cannot be trusted.

Comment: That's a problem, since you can't ALWAYS rely on one monthly reading being lower than the previous one to alert you to a RESET. Indeed, what if you have a RESET in late June, so you get a reading of 200 for that month (say), then another RESET in early July and the reading for July is 600? You won't know that was a second RESET in consecutive months by just comparing the values; you'll think the correct usage for July is 400. I don't think there's a technological (database) answer - it's a business issue.

Comment: Also, DOWNspikes may occur at RESET times; if reading starts anew on June 28, then the reading for June will be very low. Not sure what may cause UPspikes; they may simply be bad readings. If readingtype is not reliable, why would one assume that the rest of the data is?

Comment: Correct. It was bad data. What I did was filter out any reading above 500 hours, which is impossible to have. Data looks better now. Is not precise to the second, but is enough for the analysis we are doing.
Thank you very much for your help. I learned a lot today.